# What is "Interaction Object State Definition"?

Tags: sobject, salesforce-classic, setup

Just noticed this "Interaction Object State Definition" in the Classic Setup UI. Curious about what it is or will be (and Googling didn't help me). Links or description appreciated.

[image: screen shot showing new item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This object is related to the Salesforce Industries product relating to Insurance Space.

This object is under construction and resembles similar object to the [vlocity Insurance](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5a4UEAR) Data Model Objects like VlocityStateModel__c and VlocityStateModelVersion__c objects for Insurance domain.

We might see more about this in once it's launched.